# How to animate warping / bending textures?

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es

I want to animate grass on the ground. Each blade of grass is represented in a bitmap as a straight (non-bended) object. The goal is then to bend the bitmap left/right in banana shape without steps.

The grass can bend very slowly. I could use hundreds of images for intermediate frames but I want to do something more sophisticated.

Are there solutions that allow to bend and warp bitmaps / textures in OpenGL ES? If not, how would you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to decide if you really want to animate the textures, or the geometry.  Morphing the geometry is the better approach and it can be done programatically or by using authoring tools.  The authoring tools approach requires some sort of game engine and importing files with geometry, texture coordinates and animation data.

Comment: If morphing the geometry with applied texture is the simplest way to do it, then that is preferable. Do you know of any tools / frameworks for iOS and OpenGL ES which support this?

Comment: The programmatic approach can be done with just some code of your own or perhaps use someone's physics library to get more natural looking motion.  For the frameworks approach, look at Blender 3D, the PowerVR SDK, Ogre 3D and assimp.  None of these are iOS specific.

Comment: Isn't the core problem applying texture to a rectangle constructed of multiple triangles? I know how to create and render geometry in OpenGL ES but haven't ever applied textures.

Comment: Yes, that is the first problem.  That can be done with code or by using authoring tools like Blender to automate that process, as well as defining the animation, camera and light positions.